# Postgres linking two tables

Tags: postgresql, update, postgis

i am trying to set up a geo data base for my company using PostgreSQL with pgAdmin4. I am very new in database administration. We need a database storing the information about drilling points. Each drilling point has a unique LGRB NR, coordinates and some other information such as geology, all stored in table 1.

Table 1:

| LGRB NR | North coordinate | East coordiante | some columns with other information |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3481/12 | 3444130 | 5284092 |  |
| 3481/8 | 3444130 | 5284092 |  |

Primary key is the LGRB NR. The second table contains survey data, since during the project the coordiantes may change sligthly. Primary keys are LGRB NR and the coordinates.

Table 2:

| LGRB NR | North coordinate | East coordiante | date of geodetic measurment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3481/12 | 5555555 | 8888888 | 2022-01-01 |
| 3481/12 | 3444130 | 5284092 | 1990-01-01 |
| 3481/8 | 11111111 | 2222222 | 1999-01-01 |

Table 1 is the one containing all relevant information that is planned to be usig in QGIS with the postgis exctension (works well so far). So, now what i want is that table 1 always contains the newes coordinates from table 2. Is this possible? How can i do this? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "LGRB NR" 
                              ORDER BY "date of geodetic measurment" DESC) rn
    FROM table2
    )
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN cte USING ("LGRB NR")
WHERE cte.rn = 1;
```

Comment: *now what I want is that table 1 always contains the newest coordinates from table 2* , I think the query should  select `North coordinate` and `East coordiante` columns  from table2. [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/pIFch07e)

Comment: @ErgestBasha I select everything. OP'd decide what columns she needs in.